# Angularjs $interval returns fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check if cookie exists with $interval. I am calling $interval on page load. This call periodically throws an error:

```
> TypeError: fn is not a function
>     at callback (angular.js:12516)
>     at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17444)
>     at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17257)
>     at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17552)
>     at tick (angular.js:12506)
```

I really don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module("appModule")
.controller("loginController", ["$scope", "$http", "$window", "$document", "$interval", "$cookies",
    function ($scope, $http, $window, $document, $interval, $cookies) {

    var stopInterval;
    $scope.CheckLoginCookie = function () {

        if ($cookies.get("Login") != null) {

            if (angular.isDefined(stopInterval)) {
                $interval.cancel(stopInterval);
                stopInterval = undefined;
            }

            $window.location.href = $scope.UrlNotes;
        }
    }

    $scope.Repeat = function ()
    {
        stopInterval = $interval($scope.CheckLoginCookie(), 1000);
    }
}]);
```

Code is being called from $document.ready:

```
$document.ready(function () {      
    $scope.Repeat();
})
```

Comment: `$interval($scope.CheckLoginCookie, 1000);`

Comment: What a mistake :) Thanks a lot. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You added the *result* of the function instead of the function itself. Calling `$scope.CheckLoginCookie()` will return `undefined`, but `$interval` expects a callback instead.

```
$interval($scope.CheckLoginCookie, 1000);
```

If the function requires parameters, just use it like this:

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.CheckLoginCookie(param1, param2);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: What if my function would have parameters? How will call then look like?

Comment: @FrenkyB I extended the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I understand - in both cases, function is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I used Str's answer, and it worked for me. 
In my Controller for a chart I want to refresh every 5 minutes, I added this at the end.
First I call my refreshChart function, so the chart loads immediately the first time the page is loaded or refreshed.  Then I call the $scope.Repeat function last in my controller.  And my chart refreshes every 5 minutes, yay!

```
    $scope.Repeat = function () {
        intervalPromise = $interval(function () {
            $scope.refreshChart();
        }, 300000);
    }

    $scope.refreshChart();

    $scope.Repeat();
```